# Visual Studio build: sfproj The OutputPath property is not set for project

Tags: c#, msbuild, azure-devops, azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to build my solution using my 4.6.1 .net core application using VSTS.  I configured my build to install NuGet 4.3.0 and use nuget restore.  After this, I am trying to build using Visual Studio Build and I get the error in the title for my Service Fabric .sfproj file.

All of this works when running MSBuild locally using nearly identical settings as VSTS.

These commands work locally:

```
nuget.exe restore "MySolution.sln" -Verbosity Detailed -NonInteractive

msbuild.exe "MySolution.sln" /nologo /nr:false /p:AddCorrelationIds=false /p:platform="x64" /p:configuration="release" /p:VisualStudioVersion="15.0"
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive? (Set system.debug to true, then queue build and share this log)

Comment: Are you using the hosted agent or a private agent?

Comment: @DanielMann It's hosted.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT I will get you the log shortly... I don't see system.debug, but i do see "create log file".

Comment: I wanna apologize, I was getting these errors yesterday.  Running today (I've made handfuls of code changes), I get the error that It cannot find my packages during MSBuild even after running Nuget Restore.  Ill probably create a new SO question and close this one.

Comment: can you delete it?

Comment: @MatthewHartz I am facing the same package issue. Did you post a seperate question ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that NuGet package `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild` has been restored.

For me running `msbuild /t:Restore` was not enough. Had to run this in addition to that:

```bsh
$projects = Get-ChildItem -Path $RootFolder -Include *.sfproj -Recurse
foreach ($project in $projects)
{
    Write-Host "Restoring NuGet packages for project $project"

    & nuget.exe restore "$project"

    if ($LastExitCode -ne 0)
    {
        return $LastExitCode
    }
}
```